# android fragment action bar menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have created a fragment with action bar menu, that menu was shown but not working when its clicked.

Here is My Fragment:

```
public class ComposeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compose, container, false);

        userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        subjectSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_spinner);
        sendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        messageEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

        userName.setText(Ezcation.getInstance().userName);
        return view;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.compose_menu, menu);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("Menu","Before Switch");
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sent:
                Log.e("Menu","Sent");
                if (messageEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    messageEditText.setError("Please Enter your Message");
                }else {
                    sendMessage(messageEditText.getText().toString());
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.messageActivity = (MessageActivity) context;
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Compose Message");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(messageActivity, "Miller-Text.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        messageActivity.setTitle(s);
    }
}
```

When menu was clicked even **Log.e("Menu","Before Switch");** not working.

My Menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sent"
        android:title="Sent"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:icon="@drawable/sent"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Comment: yeah just seen now @0X0nosugar missed it before

Comment: are you sure you are inflating the correct menu?

Comment: yes,I'm sure that is my menu

Comment: and do you return true or call super.onOptionsItemSelected() in the Activity's  onOptionsItemSelected()? I think the poster of the just-deleted answer was on the right track but unfortunately it's gone

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
        }
        return true;
    }`   this is in my activity

Comment: sorry i had to delete my answer because of some spammer.

Comment: @RathinaSabapathiM add super on in your activity class

Comment: @Shinil M S - yeah, a little bit on the rude side. I was on the point of flagging the comment when the whole post went blank. Could you please undelete it? You're 100% right about having to return false from the Activity method  - I just checked one of my own (working ) apps to make sure

Comment: Yeah, now its working thank you guys.

Comment: @RathinaSabapathiM the accepted answer is wrong

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: @ShinilMS check my answer for the recommended approach

Comment: Oh, I will check.

Comment: @ColdFire Thank You. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Future visiters you should use this in Activity class:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

To work properly hardcoding false isnt the right way

Comment: "Hardcoding" sounds like "taboo". I always thought returning "true" means my method handled the event and returning "false" means I'm not interested, let the next one have their chance. Is it really more than a matter of style? That is, if I know there's another interested party.

Comment: @0X0nosugar from the method docs Derived classes should call through to the base class for it to perform the default menu handling.

Comment: @0X0nosugar well you are right about true and false but my point was about hardcoding only

Comment: thanks :) I've been thinking these last minutes the last sentence in my other comment is a good reason why calling super is considered a good practice. Maintenance and so on.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your Activity.

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);;
}
```

Comment: If your Activity's onOptionsItemSelected method returs true, the call is consumed in activity and Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected is not called. So, return false in your Activity onOptionsItemSelected method or parent class implementation via super.onOptionsItemSelected call (default implementation returns false).

Comment: I think you have to return false from the Activity method

Comment: yea thats what I meant. FragmentActivity is the activity which the fragment is connected to.

Comment: Well, one can get it wrong, obviously :-(   Perhaps say someting like "the hosting activity"?

Answer (score 0):

The `super call` is missing inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.compose_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```